# How to draw, write or simply use Canvas on achartengine?

Tags: android, canvas, achartengine

I am using achartengine and i need some way to draw text and annotations on the graph. Additionally when I slide the graph horizontally the annotations move as well. Is there any way to do it or do I have to implement my own drawing method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited achartengine source code to add annotations capabilities. You can see it [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/achartengine/mNAv9owZ7JY).